# IBMQ Open Plan Access: How many circuits can i run per job? How many jobs can i run in general?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

I think my question is not difficult at all, but I don't find any Information about the Open Plan of IBMQ. Such as how many circuits I can run per job and so on.

I could not find the EULA too, I thought maybe the information I was looking for is there.

To get more depth into the question. Does the account can run X Circuits or is the account limited by the number of jobs? Is the limitation for each device different or do I have a limit of jobs over all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/admin/docs/admin/manage/instance#open-plan):

> this instance limits the number of jobs that can be executed or queued
> on a given device at any one time to a maximum of five

.

It doesn't call out maximum gates as that is determined by the resouce in question. If you look at the system configuration docs: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/configuration. Each instance you have access to will have `Max shots` and `Max circuits` that you can submit. You can programatically get this information with the configuration method on the backend object: `backend.configuration()`

Comment: Thank you, I found the max_circuits that can be submitted, I think they renamed it to max_experiemnts() actually (or at least in the docs)

Do you know, if there is a limit of jobs one account can submit?

Comment: No I think it's just a limit on a per-machine basis. So whatever machine you have access to you can only submit 5 at a time.